# Is there a full map of Narnia?

Tags: the-chronicles-of-narnia, cs-lewis, map

Is there any map that shows the whole of Narnia? Each of the seven books seem to include a different map.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Yes.

I don't know what editions you have where each of the seven books includes a different map, but in the beautiful editions I first read as a child, the following map was printed inside the front cover of several (probably all) of the books. It was drawn by [Pauline Baynes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauline_Baynes), the official illustrator of the *Narnia* series, and shows **Narnia and the surrounding countries** (Archenland, Calormene, the Wild Lands of the North, and the Great Eastern Ocean).

Note the many small circular icons (which need a magnifying glass to be properly appreciated) depicting significant scenes from the books which took place at the location marked, as well as the seven larger circles representing the seven books of the series. This map is a marvellous work of art.

[image]

Here's a version which is more faded and doesn't have such full colours, but has more resolution (click to enlarge) so that you can actually see all the little icons and read all the writing:

[image]

If you're a fan of the Narnia books, it's worth taking a long time poring over this map, reading everything, remembering the books, and appreciating how all the different places tie together.

Comment: I have hand-drawn and painted with watercolor a Narnia map inspired by Pauline Baynes' map above. I added many more destinations and landmarks after reading the books with my kids! It's available to view (or purchase!!) [here, in two sizes.](https://www.etsy.com/listing/591968225/chronicles-of-narnia-watercolor-map?ref=shop_home_feat_2)

Comment: @Elizabeth I've converted your answer to a comment since you would need to include an image of the map in your answer and I wasn't sure if you'd be willing to do that. If you do want to include an image of your map I can restore your answer and add an image of it. Welcome to [scifi.se]!

Comment: Not sure who drew them, but I think [these](https://www.narnia.com/narnia-maps-prince-caspian/) [were](https://www.narnia.com/narnia-maps-voyage-dawn-treader/) the types of maps in the books I read.

Comment: @ibid - the links seem to have died

Comment: @Greenonline - https://www.narnia.com/narnia-news/narnia-maps-prince-caspian, https://www.narnia.com/narnia-news/narnia-maps-voyage-of-the-dawn-treader

Answer (score 10):

A slightly different map, by David Bedell (1976), is shown on [Wikipedia - Narnia (World)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narnia_(world)). As the original image is over 2MB, I can't include it inline, in this answer, but here is a direct link to the original image [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narnia_(world)#/media/File:Narnian.world.map.jpg)<sup>1</sup>.

Here is slightly reduced quality version:

[image: Map of Narnia World - David Bedell]

This map is somewhat larger than the image provided by Rand al'Thor in his answer above. It also details the *Eastern Ocean* a little more, as well as showing the *Silver Sea*.

*Telmar* is also illustrated, rather than just having the "Pass to Telmar". Unfortunately, though, due to the overall breadth of the map, the detail of Narnia *itself* is a little cramped.

---

#### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> Unfortunately, this map appears to have been removed from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narnia_(world)) on 1 June 2021, see [history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:MobileDiff/1026260344).

Reason:

> remove two WP:OR flags and File:Narnian.world.map.jpg which is either OR or copyvio [sic]

Comment: How canon is this version of the map?

Comment: Hmmm, good point. The only information that I can really find is from the [Wikipedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Narnian.world.map.jpg) page: _Map of Narnian world as described in The Chronicles of Narnia by C.S. Lewis 1976_. I can not find much (any?) information about Bedell himself, or the map. The map is referenced in a number of articles, for example: [1](https://theamericanscholar.org/the-high-road-to-narnia/) and [2](http://www.lindaborromeo.com/single-post/2016/11/18/Why-C-S-Lewis-Broke-the-Rules-Writing-the-Classic-Tales-of-Narnia).

Comment: Those articles might not have done any research beyond Wikipedia